# Missing tables when using read_html and html_nodes in rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

Apologies for what feels like a dumb question. I'm trying to scrape some of the tables from this recently redesigned page, but only the first table on the page is showing up when I run my code

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bazemke01.html'
webpage <- read_html(url)
tables <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
per_game_table <- html_table(tables)[[1]]
```

I'm not sure how to find the remaining tables on the page if they aren't showing up in the html_nodes. They look like tables to me. I've tried html_nodes using their xpaths and selectors, but they just don't seem to be there.

Trying to get the next table will give me a subscript out of bounds error.

```
next_table <- html_table(tables)[[2]]
Error in html_table(tables)[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens when you try to do `next_table <- html_table(tables)[[2]]`?

Comment: I get a subscript out of bounds error,  2nd table doesn't seem to exist